# Create a FAQ in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

How can I create a FAQ in SharePoint 2013? I have no idea about this, I'm new to SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below steps:

1. Create a custom list. Name it FAQ or something.
2. Edit the Title column and rename it Question.
3. Add a new Column of type Multi-Line Text and name it Answer
4. Modify the default view to only show those 2 columns and set the
   style to Newsletter.
   [image][image]

You can then place this on a page using a ListView Web Part or just link directly to the main view.

see More at http://thechriskent.com/2012/03/09/simple-sharepoint-faq-in-5-minutes/

Another option you can check here http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-create-faq-in-sharepoint-with.html

Comment: ++Suggestion Using group by option on question will make us to have collapse option in the webpart

Answer (score 1):

I'd use normal Discussion Board for this, as there you can mark items as "Question", as well as mark "Best answer".

Other more custom is to create custom list with specific fields for "Question" and "Answer".

Difference between the two is that Discussion Board is more suitable for gathering answers from broad mass of users. Second one is better if you have centralized team answering the questions with "official" answers, as well if you'd like to have way to moderate questions and answers in more strict way.